# Laravel conditional form select

Tags: php, laravel

I have two fields in a form which are connected one to another. Models are `City` and `State` where one `State` can have more `Cities`. I would like to set up my forms so that I have a filter on `Cities` depending on what `State` I selected. This doesn't work because it doesn't dynamically add it. What is the best approach for it?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('state_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="state_id">Select State</label>
        {!! Form::select('state_id', $states, 'Select State',['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Select State']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('city_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="city_id">Select City</label>
        {!! Form::select('city_id', $cities, 'Select City',['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Select City']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like this. Instead  make your `city` drop down initially blank with only `Select City` in it like:

```
{!! Form::select('city_id', ['' => 'Select City'],['class' => 'form-control') !!}
```

And on the selection of state dropdown make an ajax call and get the `option` set and append in the above dropdown.